# How to make a cron job for sugarcrm?

Tags: php, cron, sugarcrm

I want to make a cron job like at every 18:00 PM it should run a file where I have a code where it will check users current password's register date and if it more than two months ago, they change their passwords then it should fire an email stating changing of password. I know a little about cron job. So, I am confused here. I mean, where to mention this code and where to put email template in the file structure? Please help me soon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First create a file e.g. cron.php and put all the code in that file..Then you can set your cron from your cpanel or server e.g godaddy..You can find the option like "CRON JOBS"

Answer (score 0):

SugarCrm allow control crons list in "Admistrator" section

You can add your code as cron function to files `modules/Shedulers/_AddJobsHere.php` or better to `custom/modules/Shedulers/_AddJobsHere.php`

Add code like

```
$job_strings[] = 'MyCronFunction';
$mod_strings['LBL_MYCRONFUNCTION'] = 'My Cron function';

function MyCronFunction() {
  //some code there
}
```

And then configure call of this function in Administrator section